# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

So I have searched a lot of areas for this answer and I am confused on what this error is doing. Whenever I press the start server button...
[image: The setup]

...I get this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll"

[image: The error]

My code is quite long but I have no clue what to do...

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private  bool isserver = false;
        public const int MAXSIZE = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            clearoutput();
        }
         TcpListener tcpl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(getip()), 2546);
         List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();
         List<string> names = new List<string>();
         bool CommandMode = false;
         List<string> banlist = new List<string>();
        TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
        //client setup
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                Output.Text = Output.Text + "You have joined as a client";



                Client = new TcpClient();
                Client.Connect(IP_address.Text, 2546);
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Listen));
                myThread.Start(Client);
                //whenever you send a message you must include the next two lines

                //Client.GetStream().Write(new byte[] { (byte)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(name + " has joined") }, 0, 1);
                //Client.GetStream().Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(name + " has joined"), 0, Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(name + " has joined"));

                //the two lines above
                Client.GetStream().Write(new byte[] { (byte)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("\\join" + getip()) }, 0, 1);
                Client.GetStream().Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\\join" + getip()), 0, Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("\\join" + getip()));

            }
            catch { }
            IP_address.Visible = false;
            Join_btn.Visible = false;
            Start_btn.Visible = false;
            Output.Visible = true;
            Input.Visible = true;
            text1.Visible = true;
            text1.Visible = true;
        }
        private void clearoutput()
        {
            Output.Text = "";
        }
        //server setup---
        private void Start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isserver = true;
            server_IP_lbl.Text = $"Since you are a server:\nYour ip address is : "+getip();
            //if You need a new banlist make sure you click here and allow this
            Write_to_output("you are a server");
            try
            {
                StreamReader readerfrban = new StreamReader("banlist");
                readerfrban.Close();
                Write_to_output("we found a banlist \n no worries");
            }
            catch
            {
                Write_to_output("Error- could not find a banlist creating one now");

                    StreamWriter banlistmaker = new StreamWriter("banlist");
                    banlistmaker.Close();


            }


            //open banlist
            StreamReader readerforban = new StreamReader("banlist");
            string reader = "";
            //read all bans in
            do
            {
                reader = readerforban.ReadLine();
                if (reader != null)
                    banlist.Add(reader);
            } while (reader != null);

            tcpl.Start();

            //Thread AcceptSocketsThread = new Thread(AcceptSockets);
            //AcceptSocketsThread.Start();

            /* while (true)
             {
                 string Message = Console.ReadLine();

                 if (Message.StartsWith("\\Kick"))
                 {

                     Console.Clear();
                     CommandMode = true;
                     int clientID = 0;
                     foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                     {

                         Write_to_output(clientID.ToString() + ") " + names[clientID] + " " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                         clientID++;
                     }
                     Write_to_output("\n\n Enter the number of the person you want to kick");
                     TcpClient toRemove = clients[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
                     toRemove.Close();
                     clients.Remove(toRemove);
                     CommandMode = false;

                 }

                 else if (Message.StartsWith("\\Reset"))
                 {
                     foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                     {
                         client.Close();
                     }
                     clients.Clear();
                     Write_to_output("KICKED EVERY BODY");
                 }
                 else if (Message.StartsWith("\\ban"))
                 {
                     Console.Clear();
                     CommandMode = true;
                     int clientID = 0;
                     foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                     {

                         Write_to_output(clientID.ToString() + ") " + names[clientID] + " " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                         clientID++;
                     }
                     Write_to_output("\n\n Enter the number of the person you want to kick and ban");
                     TcpClient toRemove = clients[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
                     banlist.Add(toRemove.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' })[0]);
                     toRemove.Close();
                     clients.Remove(toRemove);
                     CommandMode = false;

                 }
                 //starts game

                 else
                 {
                     foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                     {
                         SendMessage(Message, client);
                     }
                 }
             }*/
            IP_address.Visible = false;
            Join_btn.Visible = false;
            Start_btn.Visible = false;
            Output.Visible = true;
            Input.Visible = true;
            text1.Visible = true;
            text1.Visible = true;
        }
        void SendMessage(string message, TcpClient reciever)
        {
            try {
                reciever.GetStream().Write(new byte[] { (byte)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(message) }, 0, 1);
                reciever.GetStream().Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message), 0, Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(message));
            }
            catch
            {
                Write_to_output("Was unable to send to any users error code 1.0.0.0");
            }
            }
        void AcceptSockets()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = tcpl.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Listen));
                clients.Add(client);
                myThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        void setname(string name)
        {
            names.Add(name);
        }
        void Listen(object obj)
        {
            TcpClient TCPClient = (TcpClient)obj;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] fBuffer = new byte[1];
                    TCPClient.GetStream().Read(fBuffer, 0, 1);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fBuffer[0]];
                    TCPClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, (int)fBuffer[0]);
                    string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer).Trim();
                    if (message.StartsWith("\\join"))
                    {
                        message = message.Remove(0, 5);
                        int a = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < banlist.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (message.StartsWith(banlist[i]))
                            {
                                a = 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (a == 0)
                        {
                            //int namespaceer = 0;
                            //foreach (char chars in message)
                            //{
                            //    namespaceer += 1;
                            //    if (chars == '+')
                            //        break;
                            //}
                            //    message = message.Remove(0, namespaceer);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Write_to_output("Person on banlist");
                           // TcpClient toRemove = clients[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
                            //toRemove.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                        {
                            if (client != TCPClient)
                            {
                                SendMessage(message, client);
                            }
                        }
                        if (!CommandMode)
                        {
                            Write_to_output(message.Trim());
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Write_to_output(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        static string getip()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "?";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return localIP;
        }
        public void Write_to_output(string towrite)
        {
            //check outputs length
            int numLines = 0;
            string text = Output.Text;
            numLines = Text.Split('\n').Length;
            if (numLines == MAXSIZE)
            {
                Output.Text = towrite;
            }
            else
            {
                Output.Text = Output.Text + $"\n" + towrite;
            }
        }
        private  void Input_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = Input.Text;
            if (isserver == false)
            {
                //send client code
                SendMessage(message,Client);
            }
            else
            {
                //send server code
                foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
                {
                    SendMessage(message, client);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Please help me...

Comment: I suspect you are not closing or `Dispose()`ing the client properly, particularly when an error occurs

Comment: Does this only happen the second time you click Start Server?  If it does happen on the first time, can you verify you only have one instance of the program running?

Comment: There is a site called Code Review on StackExchange.

Comment: @LexLi where this question is completely and utterly off-topic. ... Code Review is not a Site intended to help you "fix" your code. It's there to improve **working** code (that does what you want without crashing or taking milennia). For more information please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you Vogel612. I am checking the instance problem now.

Comment: @Vogel612 It was not the instance problem. It looks as if it is something to do with when I start the tcp listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the port TCP 2546 is not busy by another process or code instance on the listening machine.
Or choose another free port to listen to.